# Invoking member methods from another object/type as though they belonged to that object/type

Tags: c#

BinaryReader class has various methods for reading basic data types.

I created complex objects, all of which have their own Read(BinaryReader reader) which is called from their constructor and initializes them based on the read data.

This means that I now read things in one of two ways:

- int integer = reader.ReadInt32();
- ComplexObject object = new ComplexObject(reader);

I would very much like to only use one method. First idea is to move all the Read(BinaryReader reader) methods into my own extension of BinaryReader and use it that way. However, since I have a lot of those, this would result in a monolithic class which I don't really want.

Second idea was to create wrappers for all basic types and then transition all of the code to use the second option, but that brings a whole new set of other problems I'd rather not deal with, so that idea won't work as well.

However, is there a way I can register certain objects member methods with my BinaryReader so that it can invoke them with itself as an argument?
Or do something similar that would have the same result?

The syntax would have to be same as in the first example (or same for any type), since the whole point of this is to avoid duplicating code to account for both of the ways of reading.

Comment: I don't quite understand your first idea. So you don't want a bunch of extension methods because that would create a large class?

Comment: This is a job for serialization and a size/payload readwrite extension method. However if your file has a set structure, then you might as well just use serialisation exclusively, and not use BinaryReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit-** Sorry, i misinterpreted what you where asking. They are called ["extension methods"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

```
public static class MyComplexObjectReader{
    public static MyComplexObject ReadComplexObject(this BinaryReader br){
        var o = new MyComplexObject();
        o.Field1 = br.ReadString();
        return o;
    }
}
```

and now you should be able to call

```
var br = new BinaryReader();
ComplexObject obj = br.ReadComplexObject();
```

---

If you are trying to avoid creating Read functions for each of your complex objects, you could use a tactic similar to [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19513/%2FArticles%2F19513%2FDynamic-But-Fast-The-Tale-of-Three-Monkeys-A-Wolf) and utilise Reflection and/or [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) to create a method on runtime to call BinaryReader.Read for each of the objects properties.

If you want to be able to pass BinaryReader to each object, you could implement an interface for each of your complex objects.

```
interface IPopulateable{
    void Populate(BinaryReader);
}

class ComplexObject : IPopulateable{

    public int MyInteger {get;private set;}

    public Populate(BinaryReader br){
        MyInteger = br.ReadInt32();
    }
}
```

then create a reader that utilises the interface

```
class MyReader {
    public static T Read<T>(BinaryReader br) where T : IPopulateable, new(){
        T instance = new T();
        instance.Populate(br);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
ComplexObject myobject = MyReader.Read<ComplexObject>(br);
```